# The mutex locks a value in a function for ever

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am new in threads in c. My code has a thread that increasing a counter and occasionally(randomly) another thread reads that counter. I used mutex in this code but my code always gives me value equal to 1. Although I used pthread_mutex_unlock but it seems the value becomes lock for ever. what should I do to solve the problem?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
///////////////////////////

long int count=0;
int RunFlag=0;
pthread_mutex_t mtx;

void *readfun(void *arg)
{
    while (RunFlag==0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        count=count+1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }

}
void *printfun(void *arg)
{
    int RadnTime=0;
    for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        RadnTime=rand()%3+1;
        sleep(RadnTime);

        printf("The current counter after %d seconds is: ",RadnTime);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        printf("%d\n",count);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }



}

void main ()
{
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);

    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,readfun,NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,printfun,NULL);

    //stop the counter
    RunFlag=1;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `RunFlag` immediately after the two threads are created, so `readfun` barely has any time to execute. `RunFlag=1;` should be at the end of `printfun`.

---

As far as I know, reading from and writing to `RunFlag` isn't guaranteed to be atomic, so access to it should be protected as well. I don't see a problem happening here (given the values in question), but you are entering undefined behaviour territory.

---

Your functions don't return anything even though they are declared as returning `void*`. Add `return NULL;` to them.

---

Finally, the second `%d` should be `%ld` since `count` is a `long int`.

---

Note that

```
pthread_mutex_t mtx;
pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);
```

can be replaced with

```
pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: That will leave the data race in.

Comment: Of course there is. RunFlag is written into in one thread, while being read in another, without being protected.

Comment: That is undefined behavior. Specified here: 5.1.2.4 §25

Comment: The issue with `RunFlag` doesn't matter because we don't care if the reader thread makes it past `RunFlag == 0` after the flag has been set. If it adds to the `count` after it's been told to stop, it's not a big deal.

Comment: There were three incomplete answers and no complete answer, so I absorbed the bits that were missing into mine.

Comment: @ikegami `pthread_join()` calls are not needed at all. There's a `pthread_exit()` in main. The mutex initialization is fine as it's done using `pthread_mutex_init()`.

Comment: @usr, I copied the bit about `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` from your answer! /// Are you sure that calling `pthread_exit(NULL);` in the main thread will wait for the other threads to complete? This isn't clear from the docs.

Comment: @ikegami It's not a problem to address things noted in comments and answers from others but you appear to have made up an entire answer that way. While "legal" per SO rules, I'd be embarrassed to do so without much original contribution of my own. Anyway, that's my personal opinion (you are perfectly fine to do that). To "in the main thread will wait for the other threads to complete? This isn't clear from the docs": it won't wait for other threads, just that other threads will continue to execution and hence there's no need to *join*.

Comment: @usr. Are you kidding, Of the 4 problems problems identified by the answer, only one came from someone else's answer. (There was a second which turned out to wrong). As I already mentioned, one complete answer is better than three incomplete ones.

Comment: @usr, Well, which one is it? You said the process won't wait for them to finish, and that the threads will continue to run. Those are mutually exclusive.

Comment: "You said the process won't wait for them to finish" I never said that. I suggest you read the POSIX documentation if you don't understand.

Comment: @usr, huh, your exact words were "*it won't wait for other threads*". /// I did read the POSIX docs, I think. If you mean something other than [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html), please specify!

Answer (score 1):

1) You also have [*data race*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-0619/geojs/index.html) as two are accessing `RunFlag`. So, you need to protect it with synchronization primitive (such as mutex or use a semaphore).

But you don't need the `RunFlag` for this purpose. Since you can use an infinite loop in `readfun()` thread and then simply call `_exit()` from `printfun()` thread to exit the whole process.

2) Thread functions must return a pointer to satisfy by [`pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html)'s requirement. But you thread functions don't return anything. You can add `return NULL;` at the end of both thread functions.

Be aware of [signed integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) as `count` could potentially overflow.